# Swift Protocol Function Overloading

Tags: ios, swift, generics, protocols

Is it possible to overload a protocol function and have the correct definition be called when dealing directly with the protocol type?

Here's some code to illustrate the issue

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
    func doSomething<T>(obj: T)
}

class SomeClass : SomeProtocol {
    func doSomething<T>(obj: T) {
        print("Generic Method")
    }
    func doSomething(obj: String) {
        print(obj)
    }
}

let testClass = SomeClass()

testClass.doSomething("I will use the string specific method")
(testClass as SomeProtocol).doSomething("But I will use the generic method")
```

**Edit:  To clarify, the code works.  I want to know why both calls do not use the string specific method.**

Double Edit: Removed the intermediary dispatch class for a simpler example

Is this a bug, current limitation, or intended functionality?  If this is intended, can someone please explain why?

Swift 2.0, Xcode 7.0

**Answer**

You can't overload a protocol function and expect the correct definition to be called.  This is because the definition to call is picked at compile time.  Since the compiler doesn't know the concrete type, it chooses the only definition known at compile time, `doSomething<T>`.

Comment: I rund this code in a playground and it worked fine: *I will use the specific method\nGeneric Method*

Comment: The code works.  I'm confused about why both calls do not use the specific method.

Comment: Both methods are used

Comment: By specific I mean the non-generic, String parameter method

Comment: you force your compile to se the second string as `SomeProtocol`, so it can only call the less specific version.

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code here http://swiftstub.com/ and it worked fine.
First it prints "I will use the specific method" and then "Generic Method":

I will use the specific methodGeneric Method

Comment: That's what I'm confused about.  Why do they not both use the specific method?

Comment: I think that's because the method dispatcher.dispatch(testClass, obj: "But I will use the generic method") receive a generic as a parameter and it's passed to the method doSomething<T>(obj: T) as a generic type

maybe something in the compiler checks first if the parameter is a generic and it decides which method to call.

in this case testClass.doSomething("I will use the specific method")
the parameter is directly a String

and in this case dispatcher.dispatch(testClass, obj: "But I will use the generic method") is also a string but passed as a generic type

Comment: This makes sense.  Essentially the generic intermediary of the Dispatch class is preventing the compiler from correctly inferring the String type.  

So does that mean what I'm trying to do is impossible?  Or could a (future) updated compiler theoretically infer the correct type?

Comment: Actually that's not the case, I tried without the Dispatch intermediary and experienced the same result.  I'll update the question to reflect that

Comment: ok, in this new case (testClass as SomeProtocol).doSomething("But I will use the generic method") you're using the testClass as SomeProtocol, and someProtocol only has the method withe the generic type, that's why the method with the generic is been called

Comment: Yeah that's the crux of it.  I think my confusion stemmed from the fact that I'm used to thinking of function calls as a dynamic messaging system.  The function definition to call here is picked at compile time, not runtime.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be picked at compile time as you said